# Complex SQL query with regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex, join

I need to write a pretty complex mysql query that takes into account many criteria. I'll try and explain it the best i can.
We have a table that holds company information. There is another table that holds appointments for these companies and another table that holds various descriptions for these appointments. I need to combine all 3 tables and bring results based on the user's search parameters.
The tables look like this

[image]

- The 'Company' table holds many details like company name, zip, address, phones etc.
- The 'Contacts' table has a 'comp_id' cell that corresponds to the company's id, a timestamp entry called 'entrydate' (it's when the contact was created) and an 'appointdate' cell for when the appointment will be set.
  It also had a 'status' cell which is just the id of the 'contact_status' table that holds a description of the appointment (for example: urgent, low priority etc)

Now here is the problem. The SQL is created based on a complex search form.Because there are different departments within the company, some users have different access to the database data...For example the search ability on zip codes must be constrained, and so do the various statuses of the appointments.
Some users can see a certain range of zip codes, or/and only specific contact_statuses. Because the zip codes are too many, the parameters were given to me in the for form of "..and ZIP code doesnt start with 558". So for example zips that start with 55 are (some searches) accepted but not if they start with 558. All this is done via php. I can create if/else statements to create AND or WHERE lines for the final mysql query. So far i 'cooked up' this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.id, a.comp_name, a.comp_zip, a.comp_addr
    c.description as status, b.appointdate as appointement
    FROM
      Companies a
      LEFT JOIN Contacts b ON b.comp_id = a.id
      LEFT JOIN Contact_Status c ON c.id = b.status
      WHERE a.caller_id = '45346'
      AND (b.status NOT IN ( '2', '3', '5' ) OR b.status IS NULL)
      AND (a.comp_zip NOT REGEXP '50(.*)|54(.*)|55(.*)|532(.*)|668(.*)|669(.*)')
      ORDER BY a.id
            DESC
```

But it's not bringing the correct results. For example lets just say that a company has ZIP code 77554. It will not bring this company because the regular expression is probably wrong. It recognizes the 55 inside the zip and it ignores this company.
I think the proper way might be something like: `'^50(.*)|^54(.*)|^55(.*)....'` but i am not sure....and i need to be sure about this. That's why i created this post. I couldnt find relative information on the net.

**What's the proper way to check multiple 'like' values with reg expr. that start with something ?**
Thanks

Comment: This is interesting question. How much rows you are getting from conditions `a.caller_id = '45346'
  AND (b.status NOT IN ( '2', '3', '5' ) OR b.status IS NULL)`? May be it will be acceptable to fetch data without zip codes filter, and then resolve it on application (not on DB) layer?

Comment: Also, I have database with 43000 zip codes, and I check this two queries - `select SQL_NO_CACHE * from zip_code  where zip like "50%" or zip like "55%" or zip like "77%"` and `select SQL_NO_CACHE * from zip_code  where zip regexp ('^(50(.*)|55(.*)|77(.*))')`. `Like` query work in 10 times faster then `regexp` query.

Comment: Because i am using jquery datatables to show the data, and count the SQL rows to get the final entries in the database as total, i cant do 'things' after the SQL. I need everything to be inside the mysql. I also tried the 'not like' solution but i was still not sure it was correct...and since i trust reg expr. more i wanted to find a solution based on that instead. The parameteres like 'a.caller_id etc' out of 300k companies usually bring back only 0-5000 entries. So its not terrible.It is fast as a query. BTW the b.status IS NULL will also bring companies that have no appointments set.

Comment: which is important, since we want to bring companies that have or dont have appointments and their zip codes are not 'blah blah..'

ps: The DISTINCT is probably unnecessary, but better be safe than sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to add a `^` to the start of the REGEXP, and wrap the contents in `()`. Try: `^(50(.*)|54(.*)|55(.*)|532(.*)|668(.*)|669(.*))`.

The `^()` will make sure that the value *starts* with the enclosed values.

For clarity, this will be your query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.id, a.comp_name, a.comp_zip, a.comp_addr
    c.description as status, b.appointdate as appointement
FROM
  Companies a
  LEFT JOIN Contacts b ON b.comp_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN Contact_Status c ON c.id = b.status
  WHERE a.caller_id = '45346'
  AND (b.status NOT IN ( '2', '3', '5' ) OR b.status IS NULL)
  AND (
     a.comp_zip NOT 
     REGEXP '^(50(.*)|54(.*)|55(.*)|532(.*)|668(.*)|669(.*))' -- changed this part
  ) 
  ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: hmm that fails:
SELECT * FROM `Companies` WHERE `comp_zip` LIKE '77%' AND comp_zip NOT REGEXP ^(50(.*)|54(.*)|55(.*)|532(.*)|668(.*)|669(.*))
, the error starting at '^(50.....'

Comment: @user1033882 you are missing single qoutes around the regex. should be `REGEXP '^(50(.*)|54(.*)|55(.*)|532(.*)|668(.*)|669(.*))' `

Comment: Thanks, you are right...i guess 3h trying to solve this messed up my head